# Spring reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource implementation in jsp

Tags: java, spring

For implementing the spring reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource in a jsp, how to refer to the key value pair present in the property file from the JSP?

Comment: Yep, now I'm sure: I'm happy Spring team decided to follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Spring [MessageTag](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag.html).

This will import a Spring tag library.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

And this will get your value from the properties file:

```
<div>
   <spring:message code="message.code.from.properties.file"/>
</div>
```